# Setting image of UIImageView for different iPhones

Tags: ios, uiimageview

I have a `UIImageView` that is the size of the screen. On an `iPhone 5`, the image size should be 640 x 1136 points (which is 2x the size of the screen in points). On `iPhone 6`, the size should be 750 x 1134 (again 2x) and on `iPhone 6 Plus` the size should be 1242 x 2208. I've created 3 different images, each corresponding to the correct size. In Xcode, I added the three images as part of the same asset in the hopes that at runtime the correct image will be chosen. Is this the right way to do this?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**Yes** it's the right way to do this especially with background images.

Indeed, for no-background images I normally suggest to use **PDF**. 
The advantage is that the `@1x`, `@2x`, `@3x` images are **automatically created** from the **PDF** one.

**!!: Remember that the @3x image has to respect the iPhone6 size, as then it will be automatically adapted by downsampling for iPhone 6+.**

You can see the complete guide [here](http://www.paintcodeapp.com/news/ultimate-guide-to-iphone-resolutions).

Comment: could you explain the PDF method a little bit further?

Comment: of course: instead of create 3 different images, you provide just the 1x size but in PDF. Because the PDF format is vectorial, the system will automatically create 2x and 3x or any other format will be inserted from apple in the future. In the asset you can specify if the image is vectorial or not. Enjoy ;)